# Sarcasm through words like "yay" and "thanks"

Tags: informal-language

The other day I came across an interesting usage of *yay*.

**Context:** a YouTuber was reviewing a book in which the author painted a too optimistic picture of how the future might look like, she paraphrased a passage from the book then said:

> So....yay?!

which reminded me of a kind of similar way to imply sarcasm:

> So....thanks? I guess.

I am really curious to know if there are other words which can be used similarly.

Comment: Any appreciative, congratulatory, or celebratory exclamation or utterance can be used sarcastically.

Comment: There's the famous example of how two positives can make a negative in Scots: "aye, right". Although the American "yeah, sure" does much the same job. "No, really?" sarcastically indicates lack of surprise, etc.

Comment: @tea-and-cake  Great examples. Thank you. I have also heard: "Oh no! Anyway.." which I find kind of funny.

Comment: That made me think of this from an old British sitcom!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4uivPpzCGo